# column's background using pseduo element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to add the similar background ( using pseudo element or whatever ) to the left element instead of right? Couldnt achive this using pseudo elements because they constantly appear  at the start of containing element so I only could achieve this effect for the right column .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 15px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.col-left,
.col-right {
  padding: 0 15px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
}

.col-left {
  width: 70%;
}

.col-right {
  width: 30%;
} 

.col-right::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-left"><h1>Left</h1></div>
      <div class="col-right"><h1>Right</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to use `left` or `right ` positioning in the pseudo element?

Comment: @giorgio, Yep, because I use relative wrapper to position pseudo  elements all breaks. There is some padding inside wrapper so I need to use it anyway

Comment: but you're using absolute positioning on the pseudo element... but you should also add `position: relative` to `col-right`, otherwise the pseudo element will be positioned against the first positioned parent, which here is the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the pseudo element relative to their column and use a big width to have overflow:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 15px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.col-left,
.col-right {
  padding: 0 15px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
}

.col-left {
  width: 70%;
}

.col-right {
  width: 30%;
} 

.col-right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top:-20px;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.col-left::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -20px;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-left"><h1>Left</h1></div>
      <div class="col-right"><h1>Right</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man for your answer. It works if I use full width container. But for fixed width container it will overlap with right column.

Comment: Seems the only way to do this for the left side is to set wrapper color directly to needed.

Comment: Thanks man, Seems I used to overcomplicate things a bit. Cool solution with viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:
Currently the columns width is related to wrapper as wrapper has the style definition position:relative. We want the width of the columns to be related to the div with class "row". So if you give position:relative to .row then "col-left" as well as "col-right" will have width as you expected.

What to do:
To get the expected result add the line position:relative to row class definition.

```
   .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-right: -15px;
      position:relative;
    }
```

Now to get the effect for left hand side add the code as below

```
.col-left::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```